# get_post_custom stripping styling issue

Tags: posts, custom-field, advanced-custom-fields, html

I found this thread: [Paragraphs removed when using get_post_custom()?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/69526/paragraphs-removed-when-using-get-post-custom)

Was hoping someone could either help me a little more though..

My code:

```
        <?php
            $post_customs = get_post_custom();
            //$post_customs = get_field_objects('project_items');
            if(isset($post_customs["project_items"]) && count($post_customs["project_items"]) > 0) {
                $project_items = $post_customs["project_items"][0];
                $projectItems = explode(":",$project_items);
        ?>

        <?php if(count($projectItems) > 1) {
            $totalProjectItems = $projectItems[1];
            for($i = 0; $i < $totalProjectItems; $i++) {
        ?>

        <?php $pro_item_post = get_post($post_customs["project_items_".$i."_choose_project_item"][0]); ?>


            <div id="proposal_item_<?php echo $i; ?>" class="proposal_item proposals unchecked_item">

                <aside class="one_third">

                    <input type="button" id="<?php echo $post_customs["project_items_".$i."_choose_project_item"][0]; ?>_button" onclick="updateQuote(this)" name="proposal_item" data-name="<?php echo $pro_item_post->post_title; ?>" data-id="<?php echo $post_customs["project_items_".$i."_choose_project_item"][0]; ?>" data-price="<?php echo $post_customs["project_items_".$i."_item_cost"][0]; ?>" data-index="<?php echo $i; ?>" data-checked="0" data-item-id="<?php echo $post_customs['project_items_'.$i.'_choose_project_item'][0]; ?>" data-desc="<?php echo str_replace('"', '', $post_customs["project_items_".$i."_edit_proposal_item"][0]); ?>" class="unchecked_btn prop_item_btns no_print" />

                    <div style="float: left">
                        <h3 style="line-height: 26px;"><?php echo $pro_item_post->post_title; ?></h3>
                        <h5 style="font-size: 18px; text-align: left; padding: 0; margin: 0; font-weight: bold;"><?php echo $post_customs["project_items_".$i."_item_cost"][0]; ?></h5>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                </aside><!--/.one_third -->

                <aside class="one_half last">

                    <?php echo do_shortcode($post_customs["project_items_".$i."_edit_proposal_item"][0]); ?>

                </aside><!--/.one_half -->

            </div><!-- /.proposal_item -->

            <div class="clear"></div>

            <?php } } } ?>
```

The issue that I am having is get_post_custom strips out paragraph tags from the formatting. Is there a way to modify the get_post_custom to not remove p tags? Or could someone assist me with converting the usage to be more with the get_field function from ACF?

Thanks!

Comment: it's not stripping paragraph tags, they're not there to strip, they get added when content gets sent through the formatting filters.

Comment: `get_post_custom` isn't a part of the WordPress Core API

Comment: @TomJNowell [`get_post_custom`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_custom)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the line breaks exist in the database, you just need to run your custom field output through [wpautop()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wpautop).

> Changes double line-breaks in the text into HTML paragraphs (`<p>...</p>`).

If that doesn't work, then the line breaks probably are getting stripped before going into the database. In that case you'll need to share the code that saves the custom field to the database.

Comment: When viewing the item alone on a single page using the_content the formatting is correct. Its on my single-proposal.php file that is calling in all my custom sections where its not keeping the formatting.

Comment: As NateWr said, the content doesn't have paragraph tags, they're added afterwards. If they haven't been added, you need to add them yourself using `wpautop`

Comment: To expand on Tom's comment, when you use `the_content`, WordPress automatically runs filters to add the `<p>` elements. These filters are not run when you're just printing the content from the post object/array. So in this case you use `wpautop` to get the effect you desire.

Comment: Ah, I see.. thank you! my updated code looks like this now: `<?php echo wpautop(do_shortcode($post_customs["project_items_".$i."_edit_proposal_item"][0])); ?>` Thank you for the explanation, worked perfectly.